# Vertical and Horizontal Scrolling in IOS

Tags: objective-c, ios

Im developing an iPad application and in my app,
Im using an outer scroll view and an inner scroll view. Outer scroll view is used for vertical scrolling and the inner one is used for horizontal scrolling. I have several of those inner scroll views as well.

What I need to do is to separate the vertical scrolling and the horizontal scrolling where wen the user scrolls vertically only the outer scroll view responds and when the user scrolls horizontally the inner scroll view responds.

Now whats happening is wen the user put his/her finger on one of the inner scroll views and try to scroll vertically it doesnt scroll properly...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First of all,

take this problem in 3 steps,

1. Enable only vertical scrolling for outer scroll view and use

`_scrollview.showsHorizontalScrollIndicator` `= NO;`

2.Enable only Horizontal scrolling for inner scroll view and use

`_scrollview.showsVerticalScrollIndicator` `= NO;`

3.Use a swipe gesture,

Use a swipe gesture with direction top and bottom and add that gesture to the outer scroll view.

use a swipe gesture with direction left and right and add that gesture to the inner scroll view.

Comment: ok... i have already done the first two steps. can u please explain why i should use a swipe gesture here?

Comment: because you are using scrollview inside a scrollview, the touch events will be cancelled sometimes and if you add the gesture, they will react according to the swipe direction itself